# Transition with 2 possible places [Symfony Workflow]

Tags: symfony, workflow, symfony-workflows

Currently I'm wondering how I can realize a transition which has two possible places.

I've the following places:

- inital
- valid_data
- invalid_data

I want know to develop a transition "validate" which does some validation and if it's failed it should set the marking to valid_data, otherwise to invalid_data.

Normally I can only define a to state (or multiple to's) but not optional states like this (valid_data) or that (invalid_data).

Anybody knows a solution for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one way to do it by declaring two transitions:

```
 framework:
    workflows:
        pull_request:
            type: 'state_machine'
            initial_place: inital
            places:
                - inital
                - valid_data
                - invalid_data
            transitions:
                valida:
                    from: inital
                    to: valid_data
                invalid:
                    from: inital
                    to: invalid_data
```

Also you can define one more step like `in_validation` and move from `initial` to `in_validation` and after that to one of two final states.

In the documentation you can see very good example: http://symfony.com/doc/current/workflow/state-machines.html

Comment: Yeah, this was also a solution I've found for my question. But what is, when I want to block the transition "valida" when it fails (due to GuardEvent Listener) and then apply the other transition, this is also not possible.